# Create a link that goes to page and opens an accordion tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap 5 accordion:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionIndexPage">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseOne">
        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> &nbsp; Summary
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="flush-collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="flush-headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionIndexPage">
      <div class="accordion-body">
[something]
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingTwo">
[etc...]
```

I'd like to create a link in my navigation menu that when clicked from any page directs the user to the page where the accordion is (`index.html`), and then also open the accordion on a specific tab (e.g. `flush-collapseOne`).

I got as far as getting thins code from Bootstrap's website:

```
var myCollapse = document.getElementById('flush-collapseOne')
var bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(myCollapse, {
  toggle: false
})
```

Am I on the right track?

**PS**

I just thought that I could store a session storage cookie, say `fromDiffPage: True`, when one click the link from another page, and then put a JavaScript in my `index.html` page that, if that parameter is true, opens that tab. Cold that work?

Comment: Could a simpler option than cookies be to include the tab as part of the url (e.g. as a path or query parameter)? E.g. `mywebsite/mypage?tab=tabTwo`. You could then check for this using JavaScript and toggle the appropriate tab.

Comment: Thank you, it could work, sure. But then what if I'm already in the index.html page? I'd need to do the check every time the navigation link is clicked. I solved with the sessionStorage cookies in the end, I think it's neater.

Comment: Okay - I'm glad you found a solution :). 

With the URL option, you wouldn't be tied to always selecting tabs via the URL, although using declarative routing is quite common. You could use regular JavaScript callbacks to toggle as normal, and just check the parameter in the url the first time the page loads. 

Also, I'd be careful to distinguish between the session storage API and cookies, they're not quite the same

Comment: Yes, good call about the `sessionStorage` not being cookies, I was in a hurry and couldn't find the right term. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved by using a [`sessionStorage` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

```
<a class="nav-link" onclick="sessionStorage.setItem('fromNav', 'prints');" href="/">Summary</a>
```

And then the JavaScript code in the `index.html`:

```
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('fromNav') == 'prints') {
      new bootstrap.Collapse(document.getElementById('flush-collapseOne'), {
        toggle: true
      })
      sessionStorage.setItem('fromNav', '')
      window.location.href = "#flush-headingOne";
    }
```